# Bytecode analysis in Java

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

I am working on a Bytecode analysis project, for which I am using ASM. Everything is going good, I am able to parse, get class and method informations successfully.

But I am stuck in understanding bytecode representation for Generics. Here is the one example from `java.util.list` when I use `visitMethod` from `ClassVisitor` to print the information, this is what I am getting for one of the method's signature:

```
(ILjava/util/Collection<+TE;>;)Z
```

Here I am trying to disassemble one by one and understanding the arguments of the method:

- `I` stands for int
- `Ljava/util/Collection` stands for it's an argument of type `Collection`

But I am stuck at generics type ie `<+TE>` etc. Can anyone guide me? I tried to search but not got enough information. If anyone has list of bytecode names can you please share me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `+` stands for the generic `extends` while the `TE` means that there is a type var `E`

Thus in the source code it will look like:

```
 Collection<? extends E>   -> Ljava/util/Collection<+TE;>
```

Take a look at the [asm user guide](https://asm.ow2.io/asm4-guide.pdf) section **4.1.1 Generics -> Metadata**, page 68.

Comment: Great and thanks. This should be enough, I will take it forward. :)